# How to get the count of file in a directory using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want t get the number of files in a folder. there are many images in my folder i want to count there numbers is there any way to do that using jquery or javascript ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Only the server can determine the contents in it. You'll have to make a XHR-call to the backend, counting the files and returning the response.

Comment: Only `Node.js` can do this for your. `jQuery` is a client side framework.

Comment: that folder is in your local machine or server?

Answer (score 4):

If the server is Apache and Directory Listing is allowed, and you AJAX' a directory, Apache will typically return a document with a `<table>` containing the files in the directory *if there is no index files present*. You can extract the `<table>` from the document and show it, or count the number of rows in the table containing file information. I would consider any row in that table having a size column with value 0 or higher as a file.

markup :

```html
<div id="fileCount"></div>
<div id="files"></div>
```

ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "images/",
    success: function(data) {
        var parser = new DOMParser(),
            doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

        //output the file table
        $("#files").append(doc.querySelector('table').outerHTML);

        //or return the number of files
        //tr = icon, filename, date, size, desc
        //consider all rows with a size value holding a number as a vlid file
        var fileCount = 0,
            rows = doc.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr');

        for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
            if (rows[i].children[3]) {
                if (parseInt(rows[i].children[3].innerText)>0) fileCount++;         
            }
        }
        $("#fileCount").text(fileCount+' files');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer.  Although, I had to use `.children[2]`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried yet, but could be like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/images-folder-on-server/",
    success: function (data) {
        var image_count = $(data).length();     
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is client side language. it not allowed to access file to server, if you are using ASP.net then use below line of code for get count of file.

```
IO.Directory.GetFiles("\translated\path","27_*.jpg").Count()
```

Comment: aps.net? you meant asp.net?

Comment: I've to open files which is on client side but I believe you can't directly open until you browse it.