# How to load images from folder by using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, load, directory

There are 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, ... in folder images. How to load all them. Number of the images unknown.

```js
} while(!img[numOfImages].onerror);

alert("numOfImages = " + numOfImages);

var 
  numOfImages = 0;
  img = []; 

do{
 img[numOfImages] = new Image();
 img[numOfImages].src = "images/" + numOfImages + ".png";
 numOfImages++;
} while(!img[numOfImages].onerror);
alert("numOfImages= " + numOfImages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    var dir = "Src/themes/base/images/";
var fileextension = ".png";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        //List all .png file names in the page
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
            $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
        });
    }
});
```

This will load all the image .png present in a folder, care that this code use jquery.

Comment: Is it possible to load images without using Ajax?

Comment: You can't because basic javascript doesn't have directly access the contents of a file system.

Comment: You can't know the number witj javascript. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266004/count-number-of-files-in-a-folder-through-javascript

You can only with ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232134/how-to-get-the-count-of-file-in-a-directory-using-jquery