# How to check the length of the directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different directories like

- dir 1 --> template 1 --> tpl1.html
- dir 2 --> template 1 --> tpl1.html

My requirement is dir 1 has all the js files, css files, icons etc.. but dir 2 will have only html file with same name like dir 1 html files.

Based on different domains on page load i need to make a decision which html needs to load.

I am using require js "text", I want to make the path of the `text!path` more dynamic.

Inside directory2 i want to check the length first, and then I want to pick the file.

Please suggest me a approach on this.

Comment: Seems like duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232134/how-to-get-the-count-of-file-in-a-directory-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean "check the length of the directory",
Use split().

```
var directory = 'dir0/dir1/dir2';
var directories = directory.split('/');
var count = directories.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this Way to check URL contains folder or File..

```
function isFile(pathname) {
    return pathname
        .split('/').pop()
        .split('.').length > 1;
}

function isDir(pathname) { return !isFile(pathname); }

console.log(isFile(document.location.pathname));
```