# Finding number of files in directory with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am totally new to ajax. I have a URL that points to a directory on a server and I need to find a way to return the number of files in that directory. I tried both of the "up voted" responses in the link, but no luck. Does anybody have experience with this?

[How to get the count of file in a directory using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232134/how-to-get-the-count-of-file-in-a-directory-using-jquery)

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: Why didn't those answers work? You need to give more details.

Comment: what are you running at backend

Comment: You'll have to run code on the server that counts the files and responds with the result. For example, if your server is running node, you could use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Comment: Try running an ajax call to the directory and put what is returned in your answer.

Comment: This is really more of a backend process, AJAX is more of just the means to retrieve the data from a backend function. For example, you could use a PHP script to count the files and then use an AJAX call to collect that data on the frontend.

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: "/images-folder-on-server/",
    success: function (data) {
        var image_count = $(data).length();     
    }
});

Comment: So far I've tried that....      I may have to look into this PHP stuff

Comment: 1252748 - I have no idea why they didn't work! I copied/pasted the code into my js and replaced the url with mine :/

Comment: try opening that directory in browser...if indexing is allowed on server would just be html. You need server code to read file system

Answer (score 1):

At backend server you have to run any of these method depending upon your language from where you can send file count back to ajax call. However client side javascript is not capable of reading directory unless you use file api and ask user to select all files which is really not a solution.

PHP

```
$directory = "/dir"; 
$files = scandir($directory); 
$num_files = count($files)-2;
```

NODEJS

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var num_files = shell.exec("cd destinationFolder || exit; ls -d -- */ | grep 'page-*' | wc -l", { silent:true }).output;
```

ASP

```
 int num_files Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*").Count()
```